# will running a js file from node modules work after bundling the project into exe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, fork, child-process

```
->root
  ->folders...
  ->src
    ->node_modules
    ->package.json
    ->index.ts
  ->node_modules
  ->package.json
```

This is my project directory.

In index.ts

```
import { fork } from 'child_process';

fork("./node_modules/somelibrary/lib.js");
```

This is working, in development mode.

I am trying to run a js from a node modules folder using fork.

But what if I bundle the project into an exe, will it work or not?
And if not, why?

Comment: How do you bundle the exe?

Comment: i am using electron js, so will use electron pacjager